# How to create multiseat application?

Tags: java, multiview

I have 2 monitors, one is primary, second one extendeds desktop. I would like to write an application which opens in second monitor. Second monitor is touchscreen monitor for customers. I would like to be this app multiseat so When customers would clicking in app it doesn't steals mouse from main monitor. The second monitor would be acting like its own device.

Please give me some guides how could I achieve this.

Regards, Igor

Comment: You will have to run two applications with a virtual machine. Or two pc's. The issue is the second click. The touch will be a click somewhere else.

Comment: I already try with windows virtual PC on second monitor but is still stealing mouse from main monitor.